# How can I do like the following route which is in codeigniter in laravel 4 or 4.1?

Tags: laravel-4

My current website is in Codeigniter: http://www.tenders.af I want to convert it to 
Laravel 4.1

I faced this problem with routing and I could not solved it yet any help will be appreciated.

my routes in codeigniter:

```
 $route['afghanistan-tenders/(:any)'] = 'home/details/$1';
```

how can I write like the above route in Laravel 4 or 4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::get('/afghanistan-tenders/{id}', ['uses' => 'HomeController@details']);
```

Then in your HomeController

```
public function details($id)
{
    echo $id;
}
```

Edit: based upon your comment below - can you just do this?

```
Route::get('/afghanistan-tenders/{id}/school-development', ['uses' => 'HomeController@details']);
```

or

```
Route::get('/afghanistan-tenders/{id}/{name}', ['uses' => 'HomeController@details']);
```

Comment: No it is not working my url is like this: http://localhost/tenders/afghanistan-tenders/11/school-development

Comment: I want to go to HomeController which have function details($id)

Comment: No the section after id comes dynamically maybe another tender details looks like this: http://localhost/tenders/afghanistan-tenders/9/hrmis-database, in Codeigniter my routs work it goes to the details function of my controller and passes the id but in Laravel yet not working, if you could help me with any wild card example